# Accessing keys() of objectcollection in custom menu

Tags: python, scripting, grease-pencil

So, I was creating a custom menu (in 3dview) of active greasepencil colors, for switching between them when coloring my 2d animation, I wrote a script which was to invoke the `keys()` assigned to these colors  but it was not giving any output nor any error.

When I used the same script with some modifications to display the names of colors it worked fine. Why are no `keys()` getting displayed?

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Menu

class GPcolorsMenu(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = "GPcolors"
    bl_idname = "gpencil.GPcolorSwitch"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        #display active palette 
        palette = bpy.context.scene.grease_pencil.palettes.active
        row = layout.row(align=True)
        row.label(palette.name, icon_value=layout.icon(palette))



        col = layout.column(align=True)
        col.separator()

        #display color keys()

        for color in bpy.context.scene.grease_pencil.palettes.active.colors:

             row = layout.row(align=True)
             row.prop(color,'keys()',text ='') #<---- no output/no error   
             #row.prop(color, "name", text='') <--- example works as expected 



def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(GPcolorsMenu)



def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(GPcolorsMenu)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()


bpy.ops.wm.call_menu(name=GPcolorsMenu.bl_idname)
```

---

Another shot at the code -
(Oh ,no ! still getting an error - NameError - name ‘get’ is not defined )

```
import bpy

from bpy.types import Menu

class SimpleCustomMenu(bpy.types.Menu):

    bl_label = “GPcolor”
    bl_idname = “gpencil.GPcolorswitch”


    def draw(self, context):

        layout = self.layout
        #palette = context.active_gpencil_palette

        for color in bpy.context.scene.grease_pencil.palettes.active.colors:
            row = layout.row(align=True)
            row.prop(color, get(color), text='') 

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleCustomMenu)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleCustomMenu)

if __name__ == “__main__”:
    register()
    bpy.ops.wm.call_menu(name=SimpleCustomMenu.bl_idname)
```

Comment: There is an error displayed to console  on executing this script, namely: `rna_uiItemR: property not found: GPencilPaletteColor.keys()
/Text:26`. Could you please clarify what are the keys? Even from python console, if you try executing key() method of color you get a message `AttributeError: 'GPencilPaletteColor' object has no attribute 'key'`. Lastly, key() is a function. I am not sure if you could invoke a function while setting the row property. (Am I missing something fundamental?)

Comment: So, for creating a custom menu  of active GPcolors , the only option that I could  find was keys(). ;This is my best guess -keys() are same as keys in a python dictionary( which is called items() in blender) and are identifiers of GP colors whose data is stored in values().If you run the command :bpy.context.scene.grease_pencil.palettes.active.colors.items() from the python console you will get a clearer picture (here the key() and value() data will be clearly mentioned).If,their is any other way to access GPcolors for switching between them from 3dview, feel free to share.Thanks.

Comment: `bpy.context.scene.grease_pencil.palettes.active.colors.items()` indeed returns a dict entry with key a string and value an object of type `bpy.types.GPencilPaletteColor`. So why don't you iterate over `bpy.context.scene.grease_pencil.palettes.active.colors.keys()` to get the key (the color name) and then get the palette object by `bpy.context.scene.grease_pencil.palettes.active.colors[key]`?

Comment: I want to try and help but at the moment it is a little unclear what you are expecting to happen when trying to display the `.keys()` property? What are you hoping to have appear in the menu?

Comment: @BlenderDadaist- Have you run the above commands in the text editor?  If you are getting any other results than the errors you mentioned before ,do let us know.

Comment: @RayMairlot-thanks for the concern,So, for "fast switching " between active GPcolors ,I was trying to invoke the  identifiers of these colors in a custom menu in the 3dviewport,In Blender,GPcolor object  is stored as a keyvalue pair under a dict named items() ,Run this command in the console for a clearer idea :bpy.context.scene.grease_pencil.palettes.active.colors.items(). Keys() stores  the   identifiers of the GPcolor objects and when accessed in a custom menu can be used to switch between the active GPcolors.